# How to add an icon to a paragraph's margin?

Tags: macros, graphics, formatting

I'd like a custom command or environment to add an image in the right margin at the top of a paragraph, which would look something like this:

[image]

Here's the [icon (as a PNG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsDsa.jpg) I'd like to use.

**Related:**

- [Icons on side of text, below section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429876/icons-on-side-of-text-below-section-headings/430016#430016)

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code using this specific environment?

Comment: I made the example image with Pages not TeX. I added the thumbnail image linked in the text above.

Comment: What type of code input are you after? You talk about paragraphs and environments... just wondering since they aren't exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell us anything about your environment, so I just picked one...`quote`, and provide `\margfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx,tabto,stackengine}
\newcommand\margfig[2][]{%
  \leavevmode%
%  \tabto*{-40pt}% LEFT MARGIN
  \tabto*{\dimexpr\linewidth+40pt\relax}% RIGHT MARGIN
  \smash{\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\makebox[0pt]%
%    [r]% LEFT MARGIN
    [l]% RIGHT MARGIN
  {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\margfig[width=50pt]{example-image}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

**RIGHT MARGIN VERSION**

[image]

**LEFT MARGIN VERSION**

[image]